# How to get running the rcp mail tutorial?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, rcp, jface

I downloaded the RCP Mail 2.0 (here: http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/rcp-mail#no1) and imported the projects in an eclipse kepler (rcp version).
But in the standard target platform there are not all necessary Plug-ins available.

The NavigationView class uses the following JFace classes:

- `org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.observable.tree.IUnorderedTreeProvider`
- `org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.provisional.viewers.UnorderedTreeContentProvider`

... but there are not available for import - eclipse says:

> The import org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.observable.tree cannot be resolved

In the MANIFEST.MF of the bundle I add the following Required Plug-ins:

- org.eclipse.core.runtime
- org.eclipse.core.databinding
- org.eclipse.jface.databinding
- org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans

Has anyone an idea how to resolve my problem?

Comment: You should not use these old tutorials. The way you develop RCPs has changed fundamentally with Eclipse 4.x

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the RCP Mail 2.0 web site it is from 2009 - at the time of Eclipse Galileo - and I'm pretty sure you need this target platform to get it to work again.

You best bet it to download and use Eclipse Galileo if you *just* want to check out the application.

But if you want to make more permanent use of the sources, you should port the sources to Kepler. I haven't tried, but this is typically a case of

1. going through all `MANIFEST.MF` and check the dependencies
2. update the `.product` file to the new dependencies

Depending on what you want to do, an alternative can be to try out one of the example applications that are built into Kepler.